# Creating array column but getting error : TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a array column from existing column in **PySpark**

```
--------------------------
col0 | col1 | col2 | col3
--------------------------
1    |a     |b     |c
--------------------------
2    |d     |e     |f
--------------------------
```

I want like this

```
-------------
col0 | col1 
-------------
1    |[a,b,c]
-------------
2    |[d,e,f]
--------------
```

I was trying array() function like this

```
>>> new = df.select("col0",array("col1","col2","col3").alias("col1"))
```

but getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Please if anyone have solution on this ..

Comment: It Worked after I restart my pyspark..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **`withColumn()`** first while creating a new column , post that you can use **`select()`**  in order to **`select`** columns as per your choice

```
df = df.withColumn("col0", array("col1","col2","col3"))
df = df.select("col0")
```

and you are getting this error because, you are using **`.alias()`** function and the compiler is complaining about that

Comment: `alias` should work on array because array returns a column. I suspect array was not `pyspark.sql.functions.array` but something else, but after restarting spark as in the answer below, it somehow got replaced by the correct spark array function.

Comment: Dont know .. I also tried with list() instead of array() , it gave me the same error